# Ionic 5 plugin undefined on IOS

Tags: vue.js, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I installed the TextToSpeech Cordova Plugin on my Ionic App:

```
"@ionic-native/text-to-speech": "^5.30.0",
"cordova-plugin-tts": "^0.2.3",
```

And used it in my vue file:

```
import { Plugins } from "@capacitor/core";
const { TextToSpeech } = Plugins;


...
methods: {
    tts(text) {
      TextToSpeech.speak(text)
        .then(() => console.log("Success Speach"))
        .catch((reason) => console.log(reason));
    },
...

console.log(TextToSpeech);
```

I'm using Capacitor

**IOS**
When I'm trying to use the plugin on IOS: I get an unknown error: error {}
When I'm printing the plugin, I get:  [log] - undefined

**Browser**
When I'm trying to use the plugin it prints as expecting: TextToSpeech does not have web implementation.
When I'm printing the plugin, I get:  Proxy {}

So it's working and loaded in the Browser, but no on the Device.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

first update @ionic-native/core

`npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/core && npm install --save @ionic-native/core@latest`

The import the plugin like this

`import { TextToSpeech } from "@ionic-native/text-to-speech";`